# Python multiple inheritance name clashes

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem, name-clash

I have a question about name clashes in python. If I have something like:

```py
class A: a='a'
class B(A): a='b'
class C(A): a='c'
class D(C,B): pass
```

`D.a` will print `c`, is there any way to retrieve `B.a` from `D` or `A.a`?

Comment: can you read how mro works ?http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: -1 -- your question doesn't shown even a *minimal* research effort. Your are basically asking how multiple-inheritance works, but this is explained quite well in the documentation and in tons of other questions here on SO. I don't buy that you tried to search and couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you suggest:

```
class D(C, B):
    a = A.a
```

Comment: then, there is no more meaning for inheritance :)

Comment: Well I assume there are other class and instance attributes we aren't being told about, otherwise this is a high-effort way to get characters!

Comment: maybe the question was not precise enough. Once I have compiled the code from the question how can access to `A.a` from a `D` object? If I have `d = D()`, `d.a` will give me `c`.

Comment: You can use `A.a` *anywhere*. In your example, `a` is a class attribute, the specific instance `d` is more-or-less irrelevant. If you want `d.a == A.a`, then assign it: `d.a = A.a`.

Comment: @user1544128: Try not to muddle `D.a` and `D().a`