# Basic python - Multiple inheritance name clash

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, explicit-interface

Given python classes:

```
class ITextWriter:
    def write( ...

class IImageWriter:
    def write( ...

class MyFileHandler(ITextWriter, IImageWriter):
    ???
```

Is it possible to specify implementations for the `ITextWriter` and `IImageWriter` interfaces in `MyFileHandler`?

E.g. In C#, this would be:

```
class MyFileHandler : IImageWriter, ITextWriter
{
    void IImageWriter.write(...
    void ITextWriter.write(...
}
```

*NB. I understand that interfaces aren't necessary in Python - they are just here to illustrate the example.*

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728527/python-multiple-inheritance-name-clashes) that asks the same thing, but was unfortunately closed due to the OP not providing much detail. There is also ones on multiple-inheritance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222068/python-multiple-inheritance-super-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238999/python-multiple-inheritance-with-same-name), but these are specific to method-resolution-order and *class* names, respectively.

Comment: why do you need that? `Python` is not a `C#`

Comment: add description or link to C# behaviour that you are exactly want

Comment: Problem in many languages, for c++, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004820/inherit-interfaces-which-share-a-method-name